# Create Simple J Query todo list

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to create a simple todo list in Javascript but for some reason when the check box is ticked, the styling text adjacent to it does not change rather the heading text style changes as per the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BCZh9/)

HTML:

```
<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" value="None" id="squaredTwo" name="check" />
        </td>
        <td>row 1, cell 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" value="None" id="squaredTwo" name="check" />
        </td>
        <td>row 2, cell 2</td>
    </tr>
</table>

<h2> Heading 2</h2>
```

CSS:

```
.newclass {
    text-decoration: line-through;
    color: red;
}
```

JQuery:

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function () {
    if ( this.checked ) {
        //alert('Checked');
        $("h2").addClass('newclass');
    } else {
        //alert('Unchecked');
        $("h2").removeClass('newclass');
    }
});
```

Please help

Comment: Please learn to distinguish between Javascript and Java. `Java !== Javascript`

Comment: I leave it here, maybe you will be interested in it:
http://backbonejs.org/
http://backbonejs.org/examples/todos/index.html

Comment: @Mikhail thanks..can this be integrated with wordpress so that the to-do-list is linked to each user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your Jquery like this

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function () {
if (this.checked) {
    //alert('Checked');
    $(this).closest("td").next().addClass('newclass');
} else {
    //alert('Unchecked');
    $(this).closest("td").next().removeClass('newclass');
}
});
```

[**Demo Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Vinay199129/BCZh9/29/)

**Even Simpler than that**

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function () {
$(this).closest("td").next().toggleClass('newclass');
});
```

[**New Demo Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Vinay199129/BCZh9/29/)

Comment: @user2798091 great :)

Answer (score 0):

It is happening as you are targeting H2 element for styles on click of checkbox. Instead use the next TD element.

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function() {
if (this.checked) {
    //alert('Checked');
    $(this).parent().next().addClass('newclass');
} else {
    //alert('Unchecked');
    $(this).parent().next().removeClass('newclass');
}
});
```